# Poor performance with C++/CLI interop with native headers

Tags: c++-cli, interop, cgal

In an attempt to implement wrappers for parts of the CGAL library I have run into some performance issues. Some of it seems to be linked to C++/CLI interop. In an effort to identify the issue I have created a simple example, making a few calls to the some of the parts CGAL I want to wrap. I don't think the specific calls are super important to the issue, but i included it for reference. My program looks as follows:

```
std::ifstream stream1("Sphere1.OFF");
std::ifstream stream2("Sphere2.OFF");

Polyhedron P1 = Polyhedron();
Polyhedron P2 = Polyhedron();

stream1 >> P1;
stream2 >> P2;

Nef_polyhedron N1(P1);
Nef_polyhedron N2(P2);

Nef_polyhedron N3 = N1 + N2;
```

Polyhedron and Nef_polyhedron are CGAL types defined as:

```
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq> > Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_3<Kernel> Nef_polyhedron;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron;
```

If I simply run the program compiling without CLR support it runs in around 10 seconds. This is not ideal, but will have to do for now. The problem is that if i enable CLR support the time to run this small sample program triples to over 30 seconds.

I suspect the issue has something to do with CGAL being largely implemented as header only. Thus, Kernel, Polyhedron and Nef_polyhedron are compiled with CLR support, making it unpredictable how often interop calls take place. The idea was that the `Nef_polyhedron N3 = N1 + N2;` call should be a single interop call to native code to reduce the overhead.

I tried using `#pragma managed(push,off)`, to force native compilation of the header, but this just redoubled the execution time to around 70 seconds

Why am i getting such a big performance hit with CLR? Might it have something to do with marshalling of the Polyhedron and Nef_polyhedron types? And if so, would it help to specify at marshalling for these types?

Comment: Might be good to put a CLR or .Net tag on here to get some of those folks to give it a look.

Comment: Are you able to try another kernel? I'm not sure what Nef requires and what precision you need but there are some huge performance differences between them.

Comment: All I can say is time it in chunks and see where the problem lies. Then you can post more specifically about the problem area. At least for me the example isn't informative enough to be able to tell the issue from glancing at it.